# Shell_Exec(): Como manter processo ativo ao reiniciar apache?

Tags: php, apache, shell

Os processos executados pelo shell_exec() do php encerram-se a reiniciar o apache. Existe a possibilidade manter os processos ativos sem interrupções ao reiniciar o apache?

Abaixo o código que estou usando:

```
$Command = "ksh -c '(  trap \"\" 1 2 3 4 15; ";
$Command .= "./sc_serv /caminho-do-conf/sc_serv.conf";
$Command .= " > /dev/null )' & echo $!"." ;";

$ExecCommand = $Command;

echo "Comando Executado: " . $ExecCommand ;

$Result = shell_exec($ExecCommand);
echo "<pre>$Result</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que não tem como, pois o usuário do Apache que inicou o processo.

Execute um shell exec com outro usuário sem ser do apache.

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ veja esta lib que pode resolver seu problema.

Comment: Esta alternativa é muito boa @Alessandro e eu estou usando-a no momento, mas estou tendo um problema de segurança uma vez que não achei uma maneira de executá-lo sem ter de por o usuário e senha root no script. Estou fazendo muitas pesquisas sobre isto. Existe uma maneira que seria adicionar uma "permissão" no /etc/sudoers para acesso sem senha, mas até agora não consegui executar o phpseclib desta forma e sem o uso da senha.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução elegante seria a utilização do comando [nohup](http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/O-comando-nohup) do Linux.

Com este comando você pode deixar um processo rodando em background e ele não morre quando você sair. Funciona muito bem para sessões ssh, e deve funcionar também para o seu caso.

Comment: usei este comando: exec('nohup ./sc_serv /caminho-do-conf/sc_serv.conf </dev/null 2>/dev/null >/dev/null & echo $!'); iniciou o processo normalmente, porém, reiniciei o apache o processo já era. Infelizmente ainda continuo com o problema.